# SPA / Node on poor connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Lets assume I build a new Single page application (SPA) on a Javascript framework such as VueJS and serve it from NodeJS.

A user on a poor connection (say on a mobile in a remote area) will have to download the whole SPA before starting to use it? Unlike a static multi-page site which might be smaller and the user should be able to start working on it much sooner.

Am I missing something? For users on poor connections are SPA's actually that great an idea? Sure high flying city dwellers will be fine but the user experience of someone on a multi-page site would be better on a poor connection?? Are there ways to mitigate that problem with an SPA and say NodeJS? Is it possible to detect the connection and route them appropriately to an alternative version/site?

If this is too open a question, please say and I will remove it but we're looking at a SPA for a rebuild and for backend users who will typically be on a decent connection fine, but I'm worried about front end users who may suffer and not have a great experience.

Comment: You can load components and data asynchronously as needed. Specifically Vue components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components; data would be loaded over regular AJAX.

Comment: Ah nice - so you can only load the bits you need and keep the data separate. That should make for a quicker experience. But its obviously not a silly question as they've had to code/plan for it.

Comment: Great question.
As far as I know, code splitting tech can be applied to load asset files separately for each page. But library files(moment, for example) usually increase app.js file size.

Comment: can also use server-side rendering SSR, you should avoid SPA if you need seo or social sharing

Comment: SSR can be implemented using Nuxt which is also used for SPA.

Comment: @Lawrence SSR-SPAs are basically just… regular old server-templated HTML pages. That's a bit of a personal rant, but I don't get how this is supposedly a new thing…

Comment: never said it was anything new, 11 words is not a rant, big social sites don't execute js when scrapping the page, so there is no way to update metatags. it works fine for google, but involves convoluted implementation

Comment: Code splitting and lazy loading components can be applied to reduce the initial bundle size yes, then it's all about planning the user's first actions and keeping them in the initial bundle to make the user run the application while modules lazy-loads some big chunks of code for a component that does a single thing in modal of a very specific page

Comment: Not sure how MPA wouldn't have the same problems? Multi-page and SSR need to have their data delivered from the server, just as SPA does, except the former receives HTML pages, and the latter receives the data itself (as JSON usually). If you lose connection only short times due to instability, you solve that with asynchronous requests and lazy loading your components so your page elements are hydrated independently, if you have to take into account losing connection for longer times (like working in tunnels) you can use service workers as a middle layer.

Comment: @excalibaard but you can use the cache to back up the poor network connection. Let's say you have a 8MB app with 6MB only for PDF generation or whatever, the 2MB could be loaded once and the other 6MB lazy-loaded or disabled on offline mode, the app would still run but not all functionalities would be loaded offline, until the network come back up. Gotta say, this is a great question and a good discussion